# why is my method's logic not outputting a correct boolean value?

Tags: java, logic

I am writing the following code for a program that returns a boolean of whether or not three consecutive numbers in an array of ints add up to 7. It is not returning the correct boolean value and I am struggling to understand why.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {       
    int[] numbers ={2,1,5,1,0};
    System.out.println(luckysevens(numbers));

}

public static boolean luckysevens(int array[]) {

    boolean isLucky=false;

    for (int i=0; (i<=((array.length)-2)); i++){

        if ((array[i]+array[i+1]+array[i+2])==7)
        {
        isLucky=true;
        }
        else { 
            i++;
        }
        }


return isLucky;
}

}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in your IDE debugger? That would point out the problem very quickly.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @Jonathan Math Take a look at my solution below, and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Two thing you have to do in order to make the code works!

1. remove the else part with the increment of variable **i** (This will break the login in the loop)
2. do the loop with a **<**  instead of **<=** (this will cause a **IndexOutOfBoundsException**)

```
public static boolean luckysevens(int array[]) {
boolean isLucky = false;
for (int i = 0; i < (array.length - 2); i++) {
    if ((array[i] + array[i + 1] + array[i + 2]) == 7) {
    isLucky = true;
    }
}
return isLucky;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leave out the else part because in every iteration, `i` is supposed to increase. If I were you I will do it as:

```
public static boolean luckysevens(int array[]) {

    if(array.length < 3)
        return false;
    for (int i=0; i<array.length-2; i++){
        if (array[i]+array[i+1]+array[i+2] == 7)
            return true;
    return false;

}
```

**Note:** It preferable to name the method as `luckySevens` instead of `luckyseven`.

Answer (score -1):

You are double incrementing your for loop and you also have an issue with your method signature. It should be:

```
public static boolean luckysevens(int[] array) {

    boolean isLucky=false;

    for (int i=0; i<=array.length-2; i++)
    {

        if ((array[i]+array[i+1]+array[i+2])==7)
        {
             isLucky=true;
        }
    }


return isLucky;
}
```